# jQuery mobile touch event handling, this keyword context, and properly using closures

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling, closures

Forgive me if I'm not very clear here. I'm trying to learn a lot of things at once by doing.

I have an event listener with multiple events like this:

```
$account.on({
        tap: function() { 
            accountOpen = true;
            ui.openAccount(this);
        },
        swiperight: etc. etc.
}
```

I have all my ui functions in an object literal. Example:

```
var ui = PROJECT.ui = {
    openAccount: function(account) {
        var $account = $(account),
            $trans   = $('.transactions'),
            $closeBtn= $account.find('.close-btn');

        $account.removeClass('pay-open').removeClass('move-open');

        $trans.appendTo($a)
            .slideDown(400,function(){
                $closeBtn.fadeIn(100);
            });   

    }
}
```

What's the proper way to send the event target / this from the event handler to ui.openAccount() function without have to repeatedly capture the vars? (i.e. how do I stop repeating myself?) Do I use a constructor? Is there where an account object with a closure would come in handy?

I was thinking something like this:

```
var account = (function(){
    var acct = {
        this.container = $(this),
        this.closeBtn = $(this).find('.close-btn')
    }
    return acct;
}());
```

And I could send the var account to ui.openAccount(), but I know i'm definitely not doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the event to the function you are calling:

```
$account.on({
    tap: function(e) {
        var my_cool_new_object = {}; 
        console.log("your event is here")
        console.log(e)
        accountOpen = true;
        // populate your object
        my_cool_new_object.target = e.target;
        my_cool_new_object.foo = bar;
        ...
        // pass to method
        ui.openAccount(my_cool_new_object);
    },
    swiperight: etc. etc.
}
```

Comment: Yes passing the event target is your best option. If you want to send the jquery object instead you can do ui.openAccount($(this)) or ui.openAccount($(e.target))

Comment: So there are more UI components inside (this/e.target) that I need to map out so I can access them like... account.button or account.exit.. so there is another step I need to construct that object before i send the (this/e.target) to the ui.openAccount(coolNewObjectHere)

Comment: I need to separate business logic from presentation, which I think is the bigger issue here.

Comment: @frequent that's essentially what i'm going to do, but store it as part of the ui.object, so as not to have to repeat that process in every handler